# How do I set the keyboard layout to something like us qwerty in Manjaro Linux?

Tags: login, keyboard-layout, manjaro

After a fresh installation of *Manjaro Linux* and selecting *2 languages* for the system, I can't access the us english layout anymore!

I have selected the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> in order to change layout but it doesn't work.

I can't login, I have rebooted and the problem persists. How do I set the default us layout?

Comment: Did you tried super + space? What DE you use?

Comment: @Braiam:No , it doesn't work.I am using KDE.Is there a way to access a file responsible for the language from a live cd?Or from another distro?(I have 2 linux installed)

Comment: @George, Is this link helpful? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/locale

Comment: @Ramesh:I changed the locale.conf to LANG=en_US but still the same.Also,I noticed that during boot it says "FAILED: setup keyboard layout"

Comment: @George, I have not tried it out. But you can check this link as well. http://askubuntu.com/questions/380746/changing-ubuntu-servers-language-to-english

Comment: @Ramesh:No it doesn't help unfortunately..

Comment: Why the downvote???

Comment: @illuminÉ: I will try it but I am not sure if it works because I can't login into my system , I am just mounting from another distro.
 I even edited the 20-keyboard.conf but no luck

Answer (score 2):

On the *Manjaro* Linux [Keyboard Layout](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Keyboard_Layout) page, you will find that they build the `keyboardctl` utility which *makes it possible to change both the console and X11 keyboard layout at once*, like so:

```
sudo keyboardctl -l us
```

For X only, you would use `setxkbmap us` (session) or `kbctl -l us` (permanent). In the console, you would do `loadkeys us` (see */usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/*) (session) or you would edit */etc/vconsole.conf* to include `KEYMAP=us` to implement the change permanently which should make things easier in the context you described.

*Manjaro* also [uses](http://manjaro.org/blog/) the *systemd* system management daemon and is based on *Arch* so the *Arch Linux* [documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_console) may provide different but complementary information.

Comment: :The problem is that when I am running a command (like keyboardctl) it executes in my other linux distro (not manjaro) because I am just mounting the manjaro filesystem from my othe rlinux distro.How can I overcome this?Running from live cd is still the same?(I can't try it right now , I will later).Thanks!

Comment: :I have already done this.

Comment: :Yes!It didn't work.I figured..I did format :) .Hopefully it was a fresh install.Thanks for your help. (upvoted)

Comment: :Ok, I will try it.But from next week because I don't want to risk it right now :) .Thanks